# Differentiate Buttons which have the same name in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

---

In my application there are two Save buttons in the same page. I couldn't find and click the second save button. But both have different id values. But still test is failing sometimes. Is there any way to find the save button exactly which I want to click. Thanks in advance!

**For 1st Save Button**

```html
<a id="saveNewUIPortButtonId" href="#" class="ui-commandlink btn btn-primary" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'saveNewUIPortButtonId',process:'saveNewUIPortButtonId uiPortFieldId uiHttpsPortFieldId',update:'uiPortGridId growl'});return false;">
                  <span>Save</span></a>
```

**For 2nd Save Button**

```html
<a id="saveSettingsButtonId" href="#" class="ui-commandlink btn btn-primary" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'saveSettingsButtonId',process:'saveSettingsButtonId nodeNameFieldId locationLongitudeFieldId locationLatitudeFieldId hostnameFieldId dconePortFieldId systemStatusPollingIntervalFieldId systemStateItemAgeThresholdFieldId consistencyCheckRevisionQuantityFieldId consistencyCheckScheduleEnabledFieldId consistencyCheckScheduleFrequencyFieldId',update:'SystemDataPanelId growl'});return false;">
                <span>Save</span></a>
```

I Tried with id since it is different. But no luck. Test is failing randomly with the error "Element being found repeatedly went stale".

I Wrote JaveScript like below to fix this issue. This also failing sometimes without clicking the save button. Can anyone suggest me to click the button in better way?

```js
JavascriptExecutor javaScriptExecutor = null;
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
      javaScriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;      
    }    
    javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementById('saveSettingsButtonId').click();");
```

Comment: post the code snipped that will help to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may have the same "name" but they have different ID's. The examples below are using C#.
Click on the first button:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("saveNewUIPortButtonId").Click();
```

and click on the second button:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("saveSettingsButtonId").Click();
```

Also the error message you describe as "Element being found repeatedly went stale" is most likely due to the WebElement being defined initially and then not being redefined after a page refresh/reload. So if the page reloads after the element was defined you will need to redefine it or directly use statements like I provided above.

**Javascript Option**

Here is the javascript option I mentioned in my comment below.
This is for the first button:

```
javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("PrimeFaces.ab({source:'saveNewUIPortButtonId',process:'saveNewUIPortButtonId uiPortFieldId uiHttpsPortFieldId',update:'uiPortGridId growl'});return false;");
```

And this is for the second button:

```
javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("PrimeFaces.ab({source:'saveSettingsButtonId',process:'saveSettingsButtonId nodeNameFieldId locationLongitudeFieldId locationLatitudeFieldId hostnameFieldId dconePortFieldId systemStatusPollingIntervalFieldId systemStateItemAgeThresholdFieldId consistencyCheckRevisionQuantityFieldId consistencyCheckScheduleEnabledFieldId consistencyCheckScheduleFrequencyFieldId',update:'SystemDataPanelId growl'});return false;");
```

Essentially copy what is in the onclick="" attribute of the button you want and paste it as a parameter to this statement, enclosing the parameter in double quotes

```
javaScriptExecutor.executeScript();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-) I already tried all what you suggested. But Test is failing randomly in Jenkins. Sometimes only it is passing. I put Webdrivewait also for elementToBeClickable. Still I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: If you are having problems identifying the buttons to click, perhaps you could try executing the Javascript (in the onclick attributes) directly instread of clicking on the button to do this. I have posted a short example of this here http://www.webdrivertips.com/how-to-execute-javascript-in-your-c-tests/

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Could you please see my question again. I updated it and also tried with JavaScriptExecutor. This also failing randomly.

Comment: You should execute the javascript code that is within the onclick attribute like this: javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("PrimeFaces.ab({source:'saveNewUIPortButtonId',process:'saveNewUIPortButtonId uiPortFieldId uiHttpsPortFieldId',update:'uiPortGridId growl'});return false;");  I will add this as an answer as it is easier to read

Comment: You are Great !! It's really helpful. I was stuck with this issue for a long time. Now it works very well. Thank you so much. Please add it as answer. Question is to click second save button so please change according to it.

Comment: oops!! yesterday the test was running continuously without fail and today again the test is failing without clicking the save button.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below Xpath's to identify the respective **Save** Buttons.

*For 1st Save Button*

```
//a[@id='saveNewUIPortButtonId']//span
```

*For 2nd Save Button*

```
//a[@id='saveSettingsButtonId']//span
```

Comment: ** Element being found repeatedly went stale, is it being repeatedly modified by javascript, or is it in a list of elements (see the package-info.java in WebDriverWrapper for more details)?  ** This is the error message while clicking the second SAVE button.

Comment: I tried with JavaScriptExeccutor. Sometimes it is not clicking the save button. I don't need this random success.